# Backbonejs routing VS emberjs routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, backbone.js, ember.js, backbone-routing

This is how I do my routes in backbonejs where the routing and its params are obtained first before deciding which external template to call. I find this is quite flexible.

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            //'':                                                         'renderBasic',
            ':module/:method/':                                        'renderDynamicViewPageBasic',
            ':module/:branch/:method/':                                'renderDynamicViewPageBranch',
            ':module/:branch/:method/set:setnumber/page:pagenumber/':  'renderDynamicViewPagePager',
            ':module/:branch/:method?set=:setnumber&page=:pagenumber': 'renderDynamicViewPagePager'
        },

        renderDynamicViewPageBasic: function (module,method) {

            $(el).html(Handlebars.getTemplate('template1')(data)); 
        },

        renderDynamicViewPageBranch: function (module,branch,method) {

            $(el).html(Handlebars.getTemplate('template2')(data)); 
        },

        renderDynamicViewPagePager: function (module,branch,method,setnumber,pagenumber) {

            $(el).html(Handlebars.getTemplate('template3')(data)); 

        }
    });
```

How about in emberjs, can I do the same - **do the rout and get its params afirst before deciding which external template to call**?

I read the documentation and tested it. It seems to be less flexible - for instance,

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("about", { path: "/about" });
  this.route("favorites", { path: "/favs" });
});
```

Is it possible to **get the route and params and then the controller before getting the template**?

if not, it seems to be the same as case using Angularjs which I finally decided not to use it because **it gets the template first before sorting out the params**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the template "post params" in EmberJs using the `renderTemplate` hook, where you can customize which template you'd like to use.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oXUqUJAh/1/edit

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('apple', {path: 'apple/:id'}); 
});

App.AppleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return {coolProperty: params.id};
  },
  renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    // send in the template name
    this.render(model.coolProperty);
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you. it gives me some hope to use emberjs as I don't like angularjs while backbonejs does not really suit my app... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function together with $route params to get customized result in angularjs actually.

```
template: function($params) {
  return app.$templateCache.get($params); // or make template yourself from another source
}
```

Comment: no idea about emberjs, my next target to learn. but I got my work done with angularjs for now.

Comment: @lauthiamkok I think this discourse source file says similar can done in ember too. https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse/views/user_selector_view.js